# Using lapply to create multiple graphs in ggplot2 based on group and output the results as individual .png files

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm somewhat new to using `ggplot2` in R, and I'm having difficulty getting my plots to save to file. I have split my dataframe by a group and then I use `lapply()` and `function()` to have R output the 84 necessary plots individually by the group [location]. What I can't get to work is having R output the 84 plots to individual files in the working directory.

My `ggplot2` script is included below. The data includes a few hundred thousand rows, but I'm splitting the data over 84 Locations, Dates ranging from July 1 to today, and Deviation [the actual item I care about] ranging from -60 to 60.

```
# split data by location
OTA_working_byloc <- split(OTA_working, OTA_working$Location)

# create plot labels
OTA_plottitle <- "Some Title Text"
OTA_plotsubtitle <- "Some Subtitle Text"
OTA_plotcaption <- "Some Caption Text"

# use lapply to create plots for each location
lapply(names(OTA_working_byloc), function(i) {
  ggplot(OTA_working_byloc[[i]], aes(Date, Deviation)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = Date), outlier.color = "red", outlier.alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "deepskyblue2") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = -15, color = "darkgoldenrod") +
    labs(title = paste(i, OTA_plottitle), subtitle = OTA_plotsubtitle, caption = OTA_plotcaption)
})
```

When I run this, I get my nice 84 individual plots output to the plot window, so I know this is working as intended.

I tried the answers found on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766486/save-multiple-plots-as-pdf-files-using-lapply-and-ggplot-fail-in-r), both the voted answer and the additional suggestions in the various comments, and while I did not receive any errors, nor did I receive any saved outputs to my working directory, or anywhere else that I can find for that matter.

Any help that anyone can provide would be incredibly welcome!

Comment: What code are you using to save the plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to add `ggsave()` to `lapply()`:

```
ls <- list("mtcars" = mtcars, "mtcars2" = mtcars[1L:25L, ])
OTA_plottitle <- "Some Title Text"
library(ggplot2)
lapply(names(ls), \(i) {
  ggplot(ls[[i]], aes(wt, qsec)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = paste(i, OTA_plottitle))
  ggsave(filename = paste0("plot_", i, ".png"), plot = last_plot())
})
```

For this toy example, two .png-plots named "plot_mtcars.png" and "plot_mtcars2.png" are saved to the working directory.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I was trying to use `png()` before, not sure why I didn't realize `ggsave()` would work. Thanks again!